# Why the fields from the form do not get printed?

Tags: php

When the data from the following form is submitted to `action.php`, it prints the second variable `date` of the form but gives an error for the first and third field. Why is that ?

*HTML:*

```
      <form method="post" action="./action.php">

            <span id="type_tweet">Type your tweet</span>
            <span>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="80" id="tweet_entered"> </textarea>
            </span>
            <hr />
            <span>When to tweet</span>

            <span id="date"> <!-- Date -->
                <input type="text" name="SelectedDate" id="SelectedDate" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);">
            </span> 

            <span id="at">@</span>

            <span id="time"> <!-- Time-->
                <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="SelectedTime" id="timepicker" />
            </span>
            <span>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"  id="schedule_button" />
            </span>
     </form>
```

*PHP:* (action.php)

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["tweet_entered"];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $_POST["SelectedDate"];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $_POST["timepicker"];
    echo "<br />";
?>
```

Errors when `action.php` is run :

```
Notice: Undefined index: tweet_entered in E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\htdocs\twibuffer\action.php on line 2

4/29/2014

Notice: Undefined index: timepicker in E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\htdocs\twibuffer\action.php on line 6
```

Comment: You are missing name tag in "tweet_entered" and name misspelled in "timepicker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

`<textarea rows="4" cols="80" id="tweet_entered"> </textarea>`

to

`<textarea rows="4" cols="80" id="tweet_entered" name="tweet_entered"> </textarea>`

and

`<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="SelectedTime" id="timepicker" />`

to

`<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker" id="timepicker" />`

The name attribute is what gets loaded into the $_POST variable

Comment: PHP doesn't pick from `id` field ?

Comment: Nope, `$_POST` uses the `name` field.

Comment: Nope. The `$_POST` variable uses the name attribute. More accurately, when you click submit, the web browser creates a POST request with key value pairs of name and value